# I'm having problems with Apache Netbeans IDE

Tags: java

So, I've recently started to learn Java, and downloaded Netbeans to write the codes in it. I've been using it for at least 4 days now. However, as I write this, I'm having problems whith it. Now, everytime I open it it only shows this:

[image: 1]

It only opens a blank frame instead of the Netbeans homepage. Does anyone know how to fix it?

Comment: Uninstall it. Then reinstall NetBeans. Let it install to defaults. Reboot your computer when install is complete. Maybe even [read this](https://www.javatpoint.com/how-to-run-a-java-program-in-windows-10).